# TV Shows torrents

Tags: download, bittorrent, tv, rss

I have a TV shows RSS feed on my server, set to automatically download new tv shows. I also have a script that moves the TV shows into the correct folders with the correct names for Plex to use (B:\TV Shows[show][season][episode]).
The script that I use watches a set folder and renames/moves the files as they are added to the folder, but my issue is this...
I want to set the RSS feed to move shows once they are completed into the watched folder, but there is no option to do so in the rss feed settings, I can set where they are saved, but the files aren't finished downloading by the time they move.
How can I get the completed downloads for only the one RSS feed to move into a seperate folder once they have finished downloading?
Do I have to use a seperate torrent client to download the TV shows?

Comment: An RSS feed cannot move anything.  This is a function of software.  What client are you using?  If the client does not have a feature for moving completed downloads to another folder, then you'll need a different client.  They generally have this feature though.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue, I used a filebot script (amc) and simply rejected all other parts of the script bar the Shows. The client I am using is uTorrent :)